# Error in SymPy's simplify with trigometric identity

Tags: python, sympy

I apologize if I am missing something fundamental. I am new in `SymPy`.
The problem arises with the trigonometric identity

```
$$\sin^3x\cos^3 x = \frac{3\sin 2 x-\sin 6x}{32}$$
```

With Mathematica's `Simplify`

```
Simplify[Sin[x]^3 Cos[x]^3 == (3 Sin[2 x] - Sin[6 x])/32]  (*returns True*)
```

With SymPy

```
import sympy as sy
sy.simplify(sy.sin(x)**3*sy.cos(x)**3 == (3*sy.sin(2*x) - sy.sin(6*x))/32)  # returns False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `sympy.Eq` instead of `==`:

```
sy.Eq(sy.sin(x)**3*sy.cos(x)**3, (3*sy.sin(2*x) - sy.sin(6*x))/32)
```

`==` will compare the two symbolic representations for equality on-the-spot, while `sympy.Eq` represents an equation.

```
In [19]: sy.simplify(sy.Eq(sy.sin(x)**3*sy.cos(x)**3, (3*sy.sin(2*x) - sy.sin(6*x))/
    ...: 32))                                                                       
Out[19]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following approach also works:

```
sy.simplify(sy.expand(exp2,trig=True))==exp1  #returns True
```

Thanks to @ForceBru for pointing me out that the == operator compares two expressions for exact structural equality, not algebraic equivalence. I learn that one should simplify or expand expressions before comparing them with ==.